# PHP foreach - return results 1 by 1

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Is there any way of looping through an array and return each result as it is calculated, rather than waiting until all values are calculated before they are all displayed?

Say I have an array with numbers from 1 to 10 in it, is it possible to loop through the array and return `1`, then `2`, then `3`, then `4`, then `5`, *etc.* instead of returning `12345678910` all in one go? Obviously I have simplified this request, but basically my loop calls a function that has a 1 second timeout, so for the user to wait 10+ seconds for all results to be returned rather than a result being returned each second is far less annoying.

Comment: Please provide some more information. It's impossible to tell what you want.

Comment: Perhaps if you explained what you meant, we might be able to help: are you after using PHP 5.5 generators?

Comment: This certainly needs more context and examples.

Comment: There is nothing like possible or not possible. depends on the coder how well he can frame the logic

Comment: OK, thought I had explained it quite well - obviously not:

So say I have an array with numbers 1 to 10 in it, is it possible to loop through the array an return 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5 etc instead of returning 12345678910 all in one go. Obviously I have simplified this request, but basically my loop calls a function that has a 1 second timeout, so for the user to wait 10 seconds+ for all results to be returned rather than a result being returned each second is far less annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, new `PHP 5.5` provides such a thing as [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php).

```
function one_to_ten() {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        yield $i; //It is like a return, but can be done several times.
    }
}

$generator = one_to_ten(); //The loop is not executed yet. We just created the generator.
/* Some big code here */
foreach ($generator as $number){//Only here the iteration starts.
  echo "{$number} <br/>" ;
}
```